# Accumulating an array's values - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

I'm trying to accumulate a series of numbers in an array `e6`

Here is the relevant code.

```
 e3 = prompt(e1 + ", Please enter few numbers (maximum of 6) separated by commas", "1,2,3,4,5");
 e6 = e3.split(',');

for(var a=0;a <= e6.length ;a++) {

       e9=e9 + +e6[a];

    }   
document.write(e9)  ;
```

However, what get's printed is `NaN` instead of the default sum of 15. Any ideas how to fix? Thank you.

Edit: Forgot to mention that i already had declared all my variables earlier.

```
var e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,e10,e11;
```

Edit2: Here is my entire work in action. https://jsfiddle.net/nhz0Lnx8/

Comment: Declare your variables with `var` and initialize `e9` to `0`.

Comment: @Pointy No luck.   `var a = 0;
   e9 = 0;`

Comment: @andirew1990 From your fiddle (edit #2), it looks like you've solved this problem. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var e3 = prompt("Please enter few numbers (maximum of 6) separated by commas", "1,2,3,4,5");
var e6 = e3.split(',');

var e9 = 0;

for(var a=0;a < e6.length ;a++) {

       e9 += parseInt( e6[a] );

    }   
document.write(e9)  ;
```

Comment: Didn't change anything. Still display NaN

Comment: Please check now. Working fine for me now.

Comment: Displays nothing at all now in document.write(e9). i forgot to mention that i already declared all my variables earlier. will edit main post.

Comment: @andirew1990 this code does work just fine. Perhaps the surrounding HTML is incorrect.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by removing ur trim() part. Now it displays it properly.

Comment: @andirew1990 Thanks. I have removed `trim()` to make it correct as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking only as far as e6.length-1, but the best solution is to avoid the off by one errors.

```
var e3 = prompt("Please enter few numbers (maximum of 6) separated by commas", "1,2,3,4,5");
var e6 = e3.split(',');

var e9 = 0;
e3.split(',').map((x)=>{e9 += +x})
document.write(e9)
```

Comment: This is for a class, i dont think it would be appropriate to use some of the tools you suggested such as map or the => as we have not discussed them yet. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the for loop declaration:
"a ***<=*** e6.length" should be "a ***<*** e6.length" ("less than equal or equal" should be changed to "less than")